# WPF|Dynamically add hyperlink to RTB text

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox

I wrote some code which dynamically coloring "key word" in text writen in RTB WPF control. I want to change coloring in hyperlinks such like wikipedia have. But when i used that code:

```
 new struct Tag
{
    public TextPointer StartPosition;
    public TextPointer EndPosition;
    public string Word;
}

List<Tag> m_tags = new List<Tag>();//list with key words which may transform to hyperlinks

//TextInput is RTB

private void TextFormating()
{
    TextInput.TextChanged -= this.TextChangedEventHandler;
    TextInput.IsEnabled = true;
    for(int i=0; i<m_tags.Count;i++)
    {
        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(m_tags[i].StartPosition,m_tags[i].EndPosition);
        link.IsEnabled = true;
        link.NavigateUri = new Uri(@"www.google.com");
        link.RequestNavigate += new RequestNavigateEventHandler(link_RequestNavigate);
    }
    m_tags.Clear();
    TextInput.TextChanged += this.TextChangedEventHandler;
}
```

Line where i create Hyperlink shows Exception "start is not expected after end".

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: I resolve the problem

`TextRange range = new TextRange(m_tags[i].StartPosition,m_tags[i].StartPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(m_tags.Word.Lenght));
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(range.Start,range.End);`